# Joomla: What is the proper way to use "content.prepare"?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am trying to put a module inside another component. According to https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla-how-to/module-position-component/ I can put

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition myposition}'); ?>
```

in the PHP file in question.

I've tried this but it didn't work for me, this line of code simply doesn't output anything to my HTML. There is no error thrown either. So is this technique still available? Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Please post Joomla questions on JSE.  I am trying to get more users, questions, activity in the dedicated community -- otherwise it will never grow.

Comment: I posted to JSE first then here.

Comment: Make sure the position is set to display on the relevant pages (usually that means set it to all pages).

Answer (score 0):

This technique requires the "Content - Load modules" plugin.

The `loadposition` you have in your code is the event to trigger this plugin : https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F#loadmodule

Classic problems in your case are :

1. The "Content - Load modules" plugin is not enabled
2. The modules you try to include is not "published"
3. The template override is not done on the right template or file, you can try just adding text to ensure you see it first.